# How can I use a while loop to generate random addition questions repeatedly?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm a beginner coder trying to make my own little fun math game where two random numbers are generated and a user is asked to add them together. If the user inputs the correct answer to the simple addition question, the while loop will repeat itself. The problem is when the loop resets, the same two numbers from the first question are recycled. I want to make it so the numbers change each time the loop is reset, thus making a unique question every time the user gets the correct answer.

I do apologize for the appearance of my code if it is bad.

I'm very new to code and don't know how to explain what I've done in detail. I've tried using the def function with randrange(1,1001) but that didn't seem to really do much. I've searched far and wide in various forums and I don't really know what I can do to fix this.

```
import random

for x in range(1):
    Random = random.randint(1,1001)
    Random_two = random.randint(1,1001)
lit = (Random + Random_two)
answer = str(lit)

while answer == str(lit):
    print("What is " + str(Random) + " + " + str(Random_two) + "?")    
    userInput = input()

    if userInput == (str(lit)):
        print("Next question.")
        answer = str(lit)

    else:
        print("Game Over.")
        exit()
```

Typical results will look like this:

```
What is 307 + 602?
909
Next question.
What is 307 + 602?
2
Game Over. #game will exit if the answer is wrong
```

As you can see, the same two numbers are paired together in the question, this repeats indefinitely if the user inputs the correct answer.

I expected the output to be something like this:

```
What is 307 + 602?
909
Next question.
What is 10 + 978? #new random numbers if the previous answer was correct
```

Comment: Put the number generation inside the while loop. After the first number generation, the first few lines of code never get repeated, only the part inside the loop will.

Comment: @Python IT When I try this, I run into problems defining "lit" and "Random" from my code. I may be doing something wrong, but could you further clarify?

Comment: @Python IT Nevermind, I figured out my mistakes. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Look at my answer... I hope it brings even more clarity into that :)

Answer (score 0):

Your essential problem is control flow. You have to ask yourself: Which code do I want to get repeated. You want each question to be unique, so you want both number generation and the question handling to be repeated.

Since your `while` loop is based on the user answering the question correctly, you need to generate a pair first. But you could base the loop on nothing (`while True`) and then `break` out of the loop if the user answers a question wrong. Also the `for`-loop is completely unnecessary:

```py
while True:
    r1 = random.randint(1, 1001)
    r2 = random.randint(1, 1001)
    if input('What is ' + str(r1) + ' + ' + str(r2) + '? ') == str(r1 + r2)):
        print('Correct, next question.')
    else:
        print('Wrong. Game Over')
        break
```

I just compressed your condition a little, for the sake of this being shorter.

I hope this helps.

PS: Yes, I was bored and I had fun witing that, so why not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here in the code is

```py
for x in range(1):
     Random = random.randint(1,1001)
     Random_two = random.randint(1,1001)
```

You are assigning random values to the variables only once throughout the runtime of the program. So, everytime you run the program you get the same values.
Have a look at the program below:

```py
import random
while(True):
    rand1=random.randint(1,1001)
    rand2=random.randint(1,1001)    
    ans=int(input('what is '+str(rand1)+'+'+str(rand2)+'?\n'))
    if( ans == (rand1+rand2)):  
        print("The answer is \nNext Question correct:\n")
    else:
        print("Game Over\n")
        break
```

Here the `while` statement runs an infinite loop and so on each iteration, new values are assigned to the variables that carry random integers.

Comment: please format your answers correctly. you even have a preview...